# Multi-collinearity and autocorrelation issues in applied regression problems

Tags: multiple-regression, autocorrelation, multicollinearity, assumptions, regularization

I have a problem regarding my final year research project which is developing a monetary model to predict the currency rate EURO/LKR using regression analysis. 
I used the multiple linear Regression method to build the predictive model. The independent variables are correlated with higher VIF values. And the tests showd that the model violates the independent assumption and the no autocorrelation assumption of the residuals. 
Then I used the 3 shrinkage methods ridge, lasso, and elastic net regression as a remedy for the multicollinearity and the autocorrelation.

After evaluating the method performances using root mean squared error and mean absolute percentage error, I found that even the multiple regression model violates 2 assumptions of regression, it showed higher performances than shrinkage methods.

What may be the reason for that? 
Can I use the multiple regression model for prediction without concerning about the assumption violations?
Is it possible to violate assumptions in applied statistics for a practical real-world scenario?

Comment: I don't think shrinkage is a remedy for autocorrelation (although it is for multicollinearity). I also think you might have gotten the independence / no autocorrelation assumption wrong: it is on the error term, not on the independent variables.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Those two assumptions are for the error terms.
What would be the reason for the high performance of multiple regression model although it has higher multicollinearity?"\
And what are the solutions for the autocorrelation problem in the multiple regression approach? I used the dwtest in R to identify the autocorrelation and the p value is smaller than 0.05.